# how to pass list of ids to mysql delete query from NodeJs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

i need to do a multiple row delete query with the where clause in list (id1,id2..)
But since we don't have lists in JS i'm having a problem with passing the parameters to the query.This is my code:

```
 let list =[1,2,..];
 let Query = 'DELETE FROM Table WHERE id IN (?)';
 connection.query(Query,list, function (err, result) {
     `enter code here`
 };
```

when i pass it this way and after logging the mysql server to a Logfile i see that it actually passes only the first id.

PS : i tried without the parentheses around ? and also doing a Array.join on the list but both didn't work.

Comment: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935358/in-clause-in-mysql-nodejs

As @hoangdv wrote, you need to pass all the parameters as array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply append the list of items to the query string:

```
 let list = [1, 2, 3];
 let Query = `DELETE FROM Table WHERE id IN (${list})`;
 connection.query(Query, function (err, result) {
     `enter code here`
 };
```

Comment: good as long as the `list` variable is not filled in with data from outside the system, e.g. user inputted data. Otherwise, SQL injection would be a problem.

Comment: There's a reason why MySQL says to "always escape your data". You don't want to find it out

Answer (score 7):

Read in document of https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#performing-queries (if you use this lib to connect mysql)

```
 let list =[1,2,..];
 let Query = 'DELETE FROM Table WHERE id IN (?)';
 // values param need is a array of value to binding to "?"
 // you can try [list.toString()] if the block above not working
 connection.query(Query,[list], function (err, result) {
     `enter code here`
 };
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Works well in node mysql2 package

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `?` placeholders don't work with the IN operator. So you should escape the values. Say the `list` variable is coming from an external source; so to prevent SQL Injection you can:

```
// `list` is filled in outside this process
const Query = `DELETE FROM Table WHERE id IN (${list.map((item) => connection.escape(item))})`;
connection.query(Query, function (err, result) {
  // handle error or result here
};
```

I noticed that `list.map(connection.escape)` won't work and throw:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined`