# NodeJS weired behavior when using IN() with Primary Key of (User-)Table

Tags: mysql, node.js, primary-key

i've got the following table schema

```
+----+-----------+------------+--------------------+
| ID | firstname |  lastname  |       email        |
+----+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|  1 | Max       | Mustermann | max@muster.de      |
|  2 | New       | User       | example@example.de |
+----+-----------+------------+--------------------+
```

Im using this query to fetch every user which has one of the specified ids in the "IN"-Function.

```
SELECT ID, email, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as name FROM `user` WHERE ID IN(1,2)
```

This seems to work perfectly, if i run it in my local phpmyadmin instance against the same table im using through NodeJS and the sync-mysql package.

My code exactly looks like this:

```
const result = connection.query("SELECT ID,email, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as name FROM user WHERE user.ID IN (?)", [ filterNutzer]);
console.log(result);
```

The content of "filterNutzer" variable is: "1,2,3" as a String.

So what im  expecting is a result which contains the users data with the ids 1, 2 and three. But what i got is only the first ID (1 in this case).

Whats so weired for me is that the behaviour in NodeJS doesnt fit the executed statement in phpmyadmin. Im really running out of options, please help me out ;)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IN clause in mysql nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935358/in-clause-in-mysql-nodejs)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer but this is not a duplicate of this. I tried the following:

"SELECT ID,email, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as name FROM user WHERE user.ID IN ("+filterNutzer+")"

And even their its not working. Query is looking exactly like in sql. So its not a problem of building the query. Just a think of executing and gathering / use the result.

Comment: Did you tried to pass the `filterNutzer` variable as array like `[1,2,3]` usually the query builder knows how to handle it.

Comment: Hey @BraveButter, unfortunatally this is not working too... TypeError: Expected every arg to be a string, number, boolean or null could you give me an example of how you would handle this query if const aArray = [1,2,3] i tried this: connection.query("SELECT ID,email, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as name FROM user WHERE user.ID IN (?)", [aArray])